# Why does 2 % 3 = 2 and not 1?

Tags: javascript

Why does 2 mod 3 equal 2 and not 1?

How many ever '2 mod 3' I put in between, it is printing 2 as the answer. Please can anyone explain this behavior

Comment: 2 / 3 = 0 with a remainder of 2. Hence 2 mod 3 = 2... 3 mod 2 on the other hand is equal to 1. Perhaps you are getting confused with the order?

Comment: Because 2 mod 3 is 2?

Comment: What makes you think that it should be 1?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about basic math and does not have much to do with JavaScript itself, but math and what modulus is.

Comment: When you divide 3 into 2 with paper and pencil, what do you get for the remainder?

Comment: well I thought it was because it has a remainder of 1 and I thought that was the purpose of the mod function to tell you the remainder

Comment: But ... it has a remainder of *2*, not 1.  If you divide 3 into 2, the quotient is 0 and the remainder is 2.

Comment: Yeah it was a order issue thanks

Comment: this is like thinking 2 / 3 = 1.5

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you completely understand modulus.

The '%' symbol reads mod or modulus. Essentially 2 mod 3 = 0 with a remainder of 2.

The remainder of 2 is your answer. 2 mod or % 3 = 2.

Comment: No, `2 mod 3` is `2`.

Comment: See my edit, maybe it wasn't entirely clear. I'm just trying to explain to further their thought process from what was suggested.

Comment: Yes I should have said explicitly that I thought it was probably a typo or just not completely clear.

Comment: @Pointy yeah no problem, thanks for helping me be sure that I'm getting my point across appropriately. I'm still working on that, but I'll get there!

Comment: @John I'm happy to help. Hopefully this clears things up for you.